# Polymer paper-button renders poorly in Safari and Firefox

Tags: polymer

How can I make paper-button render at its full size all at once in Safari and Firefox? Renders well in Chrome, but in the other two browsers it renders without proper padding and then "clicks" into it's proper display.

Thanks

http://107.170.93.84/